# 2 hard drives on MacBook 12 inch

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, usb, ssd

I have a MacBook 12 inch with 1 USB-C port.
My MacBook got too small for my Photo's library, so I put that on an external SSD.

Now I want to include that SSD into the TimeMachine backup. The only way to do that is of course to have it connected at the same time as the TimeMachine backup disk.

I have a Satechi USB-C hub (I think [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B019PHF9UY) one) to connect them. But now it seems that TimeMachine gets stuck at 250MB or 1GB (tried several times). Also when trying to eject the TimeMachine disk, Finder stops responding.

Is what I want to do possible at all? I hope so, since it's quite a basic feature...
Thanks

Comment: Are your SSD or backup disk self powered or do they rely on power from the hub? It would help if the question specified what model SSD and backup disk?

Comment: The SSD is a Sandisk Extreme V2, the backup disk is a 2.5" USB 3 from WD. They are relying on the hub -> the macbook charger is in the hub too.

Comment: I also connected a stronger charger of an M1 MacBook Pro 13", to see if more available power helps. It unfortunately doesn't.

Comment: I strongly suspect that power is your problem trying to read/write both drives at once. I don't think changing the charger helps because of the way power works with that sort of hub with pass thru charging of the MacBook.  It would interesting to see how you might go wth a powered USB 3 hub - but you wouldn't be able to charge the MacBook at the same time. [I have a 2016 MacBook but only ever connect one SSD at time via the Apple dock]. Do you have a desktop computer?

Comment: I don't have a desktop computer. `but you wouldn't be able to charge the MacBook at the same time.` -> that's a problem as it's a 500GB backup and my macbook doesn't go that long without charging

Comment: It sounds very weird that it wouldn't be possible to have 2 disks connected to the MacBook at once. It sounds like it should be a basic functionality, right? What if I want to just copy something from 1 drive to the other?

Comment: Assuming it is a power issue, you need a powered hub (wth 2 or more USB ports) which is also capable of charging the MacBook. The MacBook (like the MacBook Air) is designed with low weight as key feature - this means compromises with other things.

Comment: Quite a big compromise. Do you have any examples of such USB hubs?

Comment: I don't have direct knowledge of which hub to choose. I will leave that to others.